# Cookie Authentication not working on ASP NET Core As IIS Subsite

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, iis

I have a windows server with several application deployed as default website sub application:

[image]

One of this application (RiskturnStorm2) is a .Net Core Asp Net application with cookie authentication.

```
            services.AddAuthentication(Constants.AuthenticationSchema)
             .AddCookie(Constants.AuthenticationSchema, config =>
             {
                 config.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie";
                 config.LoginPath = "/Login";
             });
```

Launching the application on localhost works perfectly.

When i try to open the application from its domain ([www.XXX.com/riskturnstorm2](http://www.XXX.com/riskturnstorm2)) the login redirect takes too much time and, eventually, an error page is displayed, as if the login page itself (which has [AllowAnonymous] attribute) performs another redirect to itself (generationg a loop).

[image]

If I try to deploy the application directly in the root of the default website everything works well (but this is not a valid solution for me).

Anyone can help? Could this be related to not-specifying the domain in the ASP NET cookie authentication declaration?

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser to learn about the redirection. That's step 1 before moving on.

Comment: What is the error details on the client-side?
Check the below link about sharing cookies across different paths. We might need to override the Path property.
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-cookies-across-different-base-paths